# How to get JSON Object, REST API, Jhipster, SpringBoot

Tags: json, spring-boot, jackson, jhipster

I'm coding an API using Jhipster. Server side is programmed with Spring-Boot. I want to get JSON Object that i send with PostMan

```
{
    "user" : {
        "name" : "name",
        "surname": "surname"
    }
}
```

I create a ressource and a class to get this JSON Object

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/",method = RequestMethod.POST,produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @Timed
    public ResponseEntity<AlertBalance> create(@RequestBody User user) throws URISyntaxException {

        System.out.println("name  "+ user.getName()+"/ surname : "+User.getSurname());

}
```

User class Code

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class User implements Serializable  {

    private String name;
    private String surname ; 
   @JsonCreator
     public User(@JsonProperty("surname") String surname , @JsonProperty("name") String name){
        this.surname = surname;
        this.name = name;
    }


    public User(){
    }
 //setters and getters       
}
```

The create() method is called when I do request from postman, but the value of name and surname is null. Do you know what I can do to get the real values ?

Comment: Your tags are wrong: this is not an issue with web-services nor java-ee. This does not seem to be a JHipster question as well as you changed User. It's a question about Jackson de-serialization and spring mvc

Comment: You are right. thank you for the correction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just find the mistake, the JSON Object I sent was incompatible. I change it with

```
{
    "name" : "name",
    "surname": "surname"
}
```

and now it works.